# Show 404 status and page-not-found View without actually redirecting to pagenotfound Nopcommerce 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-core, nopcommerce, asp.net-core-middleware, nopcommerce-4.5

Using Nopcommerce V.4.5

Whenever there is a 404 error it redirect to /pagenotfound.

I am trying for it to show the same View on the original URL that was 404.

So far:

I have added a custom middleware on `NopRoutingStartup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
  application.UseMiddleware<Custom404Middleware>();
  application.UseMiniProfiler();
  application.UseRouting();
}
```

Custom404Middleware.cs

```
    internal class Custom404Middleware
    {
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public Custom404Middleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
        var originalQueryString = context.Request.QueryString.Value;
        await _next(context);

        if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound && !context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
           
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Custom 404 Page Not Found");

           }
       }
   }
```

It works and I see : `Custom 404 Page Not Found` on 404.  How can I here show the View I want?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You have a client and server.  The client sent a request to server, but credentials that were used did not have permission to access the route.  What are you trying to do?  What View are you referring to?  A view on the client or a view on the server?

Comment: Befault nopcommerce serves the Client with a Pagenotfound.cshtml view on a 404 basically it redirects to /pagenotfound so that view is loaded automaically. I want it not redirect to another URL and still show that view.

Comment: You want a default route on the server controller : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#conventional-routing

Comment: i already have that:

 name: "PageNotFound",
 pattern: "page-not-found",
 defaults: new { controller = "Common", action = "PageNotFound" });

but it does not get hit.

even if I do this in middleware:

context.Response.Clear();
context.Request.Path = "/page-not-found";
await _next(context);

Comment: You must be getting an exception for some other reason.  Try to find where the code is actually going.  You could be getting a 500 error which is Internal Server Error.  Or credentials are failing.  Are you using Authorize?  If you are not authorize you will never get to the page not found.  See : https://auth0.com/blog/permission-based-security-aspnet-webapi/

Comment: its a 404 error which comes when I put a wrong URL. I know it because it goes inside:

 if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound

Comment: You are not getting the question, everythign works I just want to know how I can show a View here pagenoutfound.cshtml instead of custom text.

Comment: Do you want the view to be HTML?  Then create an HTML view instead of text.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-create-an-html-document-viewer-in-a-windows-forms-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: Surprisingly just doing this does the trick:

public static void UsePageNotFound_Works(this IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    application.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/page-not-found", "?statusCode={0}");
}

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest returning views in middleware how ever if you wanna do that, here's your updated invoke function:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    var originalPath = context.Request.Path.Value;
    var originalQueryString = context.Request.QueryString.Value;
    await _next(context);

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound && !context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
       
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Custom 404 Page Not Found");
        var actionContext = new ActionContext(context, context.GetRouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());

        var executor = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IActionResultExecutor<ViewResult>>();

        var viewResult = new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = "PageNotFound",
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound,
            ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary(
                           new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
        };

        await executor.ExecuteAsync(actionContext, viewResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).